# Why is my CSS stylesheet not linking to my HTML file?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get my html file to link with the external stylesheet I am trying to apply. Both files are located in the same folder and the filenames are accurate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Assignment 3</title>
    <link rel=”stylesheet” href=”assign_3_style.css”>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Sandy's Sandwiches </h1> 
  </body>
</html>

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

body {  max-width:325;  }

h1 {    
  border:3px inset #2E4053;
  color:#0B5345;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using typographic quotes in there:

```
<link rel=”stylesheet” href=”assign_3_style.css”>
```

Those won't work in code - change them to plain quotes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assign_3_style.css">
```

P.S.: `max-width:325;` won't work either, you need to specify a unit, like "px": `max-width:325px;`